# Associate a form with every item in a list

Tags: django

I am using Django 1.5 and I'm trying to create a list and to associate a form (with choice field) with every item in the list, from where to change some data for that object.

I encountered the following problems:

PROBLEM1: how to get the pk of the appropiate object, in order to update it in db ?

PROBLEM2: when I make a post request, the data is changing in all forms, each form will have the *changed* data for the choicefield

If this is not a proper way to achieve the desired behaviour please bring the light on my street!

Tx!

Below is some sample code.

View:

```
class MyListView(ListView, FormMixin):
        model = MyModel()
        queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
        form_class = MyForm

        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(MyListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            form_class = self.get_form_class()
            context['form'] = self.get_form(form_class)
            return context

        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            form_class = self.get_form_class()
            form = self.get_form(form_class)
            if form.is_valid():        
                update_obj = MyModel.objects.get(pk= PROBLEM1 )
                ...
                update_obj.save()
            else:
                print form.errors
            return self.get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Form:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
        CHOICES=(
                    ('one','one'),
                    ('two','two')
                )
        nr = forms.ChoiceField(widget = forms.Select, choices = CHOICES)
```

Template:

```
{% for item in object_list %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ item.title }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.nr}}
                    <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form.as_p }} <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can anyone give me more hints?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets).

Comment: Tx! but can you give me more clues, some examples?

Comment: Did you read that documentation? There are plenty of examples there.